# Insert alternating formulas into the same column

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to use vba to insert 2 different formulas into the **same** column? I want the formulas to alternate. I'm trying to do Sumif's but the sum range keeps changing after every second line, so I need to be able to insert 2 different formulas.

So to try to explain this further - Say in Cell A1 I want to use a sumif and the sum range is column K, but then A2 has to sum column L, and then A3 has to go back to column K and so on.

I tried to use using a vlookup , but there is no unique identifier.

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use `Step 2` in your loop.

You will need to adjust the loop range of course as this is just a generic example. If you drop this in a worksheet code space and run, you will notice every other row switches between summing `Column K` and `Column L`

---

```
Sub Alternate()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 20 Step 2
    Range("A" & i).Formula = "=Sum(K:K)"
    Range("A" & i + 1).Formula = "=Sum(L:L)"
Next i


End Sub
```

*Also, qualify your objects properly unlike the above example!*

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You also do this in Excel using the ROW function:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)<>0,SUM(K:K),SUM(L:L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Without loop:

```
Sub FFF()
    [A1].Formula = "=SUM(K:K)"
    [A2].Formula = "=SUM(L:L)"
    [A1:A2].AutoFill [A1:A20]
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The WorksheetFunction property is also very useful for a requirement like this. All of the calculation happens in VBA instead of on the sheet itself.

```
Sub Alternate()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 20 Step 2
        Range("A" & i) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("J:J"), criteria, Range("K:K"))
        Range("A" & i + 1) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("J:J"), criteria, Range("L:L"))
    Next i
End Sub
```

...where "criteria" is something like ">10" or "whateverString"